# tideSDK autorun program

Tags: exe, tidesdk, autorun

I am creating an exe application with tideSDK and I wondering is it possible to make my program autorunning with system. It can be installer or anything else, but I am searching any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on operating system you need to do different things to achieve what you want.

For windows you can place the shortcut in `Start -> All Programs --> Startup` folder to start your application at Startup time.

For linux systems you need to modify init scripts.

Comment: Ok, i forgot mentioned that should be something what can be done automatically. I am creating .exe for user and I treat him like a noob. User task is to only install program, nothing more.

Comment: It seems u need to create custom installer for your application. Depending on operating system u can create custom installers.

Comment: Is it possible in tideSDK ?

Comment: Everything is possible to code :D http://coastalforge.com provides professional support for TideSDK. contact us at help@coastalforge.com